# Presto window function get only top 10 records of each group

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto, amazon-athena

I am using **window function** on **Presto** to group each partition the result is returning as extected but I want to grab only top 10 records of each partition. But If I apply LIMIT 10 then it returns only 10 rows among all partition not individual partition. **Note:** I've seen similar question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303343/t-sql-to-find-top-10-records-for-each-group) but it seems complicated. Is there any easy way to fix this?

**Query Used:**

```
WITH TOP_USERS AS (
 SELECT NAME, UNAME, DATE,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,UNAME ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS RN FROM TABLE_NAME 
)
SELECT * FROM TOP_USERS WHERE RN=1  ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 100
```

**Current Result:**

```
NAME    UNAME             DATE                  RN
BBIG    StockHighArmy   2021-01-07 01:07:04.000 1
BCII    VinnytheLEFT    2021-01-07 09:54:35.000 1
BEGI    RadioSilentplay 2021-01-07 10:38:45.000 1
BEGI    aheadsupotc 2021-01-07 10:42:51.000     1
BETRF   greg_lechuga    2021-01-07 09:23:55.000 1
BIEI    trade_dr    2021-01-07 08:57:10.000     1
BIEI    ThornLeafArtist 2021-01-07 09:20:37.000 1
BIEI    Vegas_Whoa  2021-01-07 00:57:12.000     1
BIEI    trader_bearded  2021-01-07 08:13:53.000 1
BITCF   OTCBullRider    2021-01-07 10:29:11.000 1
BKLLF   OddStockTrader  2021-01-07 10:04:45.000 1
BLDV    A10_Vet 2021-01-07 10:33:19.000         1
BLPG    NedGreen5   2021-01-07 09:54:07.000     1
BLPG    ThebuyG 2021-01-07 09:38:16.000         1
BLPG    StockRocket1    2021-01-07 09:20:20.000 1
BLPG    aheadsupotc 2021-01-07 09:57:30.000     1
BLPG    mando2250   2021-01-07 01:39:52.000     1
BLPG    crabbermike 2021-01-07 08:28:08.000     1
BLPG    Scottspg1033    2021-01-07 06:20:08.000 1
BLPG    thestocks7889   2021-01-07 00:24:06.000 1
BLPG    koba19822012    2021-01-07 09:28:15.000 1
BLPG    StockStar319    2021-01-07 09:32:11.000 1
BLPG    rrr1sr  2021-01-07 09:16:25.000         1
BLPG    BodaciousTrade  2021-01-07 09:52:49.000 1
BLPG    TheChaseGroup1  2021-01-07 06:23:58.000 1
BLPG    rj34704726  2021-01-07 00:57:22.000     1
BLPG    claydeath1  2021-01-07 09:22:35.000     1
BLPG    Chivitotrader   2021-01-07 09:38:08.000 1
```

**Expected Result:** (**SEE BLPG has only 10 rows**)

```
NAME    UNAME             DATE                  RN
BBIG    StockHighArmy   2021-01-07 01:07:04.000 1
BCII    VinnytheLEFT    2021-01-07 09:54:35.000 1
BEGI    RadioSilentplay 2021-01-07 10:38:45.000 1
BEGI    aheadsupotc 2021-01-07 10:42:51.000     1
BETRF   greg_lechuga    2021-01-07 09:23:55.000 1
BIEI    trade_dr    2021-01-07 08:57:10.000     1
BIEI    ThornLeafArtist 2021-01-07 09:20:37.000 1
BIEI    Vegas_Whoa  2021-01-07 00:57:12.000     1
BIEI    trader_bearded  2021-01-07 08:13:53.000 1
BITCF   OTCBullRider    2021-01-07 10:29:11.000 1
BKLLF   OddStockTrader  2021-01-07 10:04:45.000 1
BLDV    A10_Vet 2021-01-07 10:33:19.000         1
BLPG    NedGreen5   2021-01-07 09:54:07.000     1
BLPG    ThebuyG 2021-01-07 09:38:16.000         1
BLPG    StockRocket1    2021-01-07 09:20:20.000 1
BLPG    aheadsupotc 2021-01-07 09:57:30.000     1
BLPG    mando2250   2021-01-07 01:39:52.000     1
BLPG    crabbermike 2021-01-07 08:28:08.000     1
BLPG    Scottspg1033    2021-01-07 06:20:08.000 1
BLPG    thestocks7889   2021-01-07 00:24:06.000 1
BLPG    koba19822012    2021-01-07 09:28:15.000 1
BLPG    StockStar319    2021-01-07 09:32:11.000 1
BLPG    rrr1sr  2021-01-07 09:16:25.000         1
BLPG    BodaciousTrade  2021-01-07 09:52:49.000 1
BLPG    TheChaseGroup1  2021-01-07 06:23:58.000 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting expected result after fixing `PARTITION BY` and `WHERE RN < 11` clause like below. But still I don't know why **PARTIONTION BY NAME, UNAME** together not properly generated the row numbers incrementally from 1,2,3,4......way? May be for multiple PARTITION BY column it behaves like RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER. Please correct me If I am wrong.

```
WITH TOP_USERS AS (
 SELECT NAME, UNAME, DATE,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS RN FROM TABLE_NAME 
)
SELECT * FROM TOP_USERS WHERE RN < 11  ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 100
```

Comment: If you partition by NAME and UNAME, the row_number() function will assign an independent sequence to each *combination* of name and uname.

Comment: @MartinTraverso thanks a lot sir, just to clarify my understanding you mean that's why it is assigning  RN 1 to each NAME and UNAME combination like my question above?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you want the assignment to be done just on NAME, you have to partition the input to the window function just by that column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `where` clause:

```
WHERE RN <= 10
```

Comment: my first concern is why it is showing same rn=1 for multiple rows?

Comment: Even I used RANK and DENSE_RANK but it is causing issue when I try to select only TOP 10 from each group